# Why do the values in my model not update in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am going to insert and update values using my addpermission function in my Controller

```
public function addPermission(Request $request, $id, $permission = null) 
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'status'   => 'required'
  ]);

  if(is_null($permission)) {
    $permission = new Permission;
    $msg = 'Permission has been added to your Collaborator successfully';
  } else {
    $permission = Permission::findOrFail($permission,['id'])->id;
    $msg = 'Permission updated successfully';
  }

  $permission->status = $request->input('status');
  $permission->project_id       = $id;
  $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');
  $permission->save();
  return redirect()->back()->with('info', $msg);
}
```

My routes

```
Route::post('projects/{project_id}/permission', [
    'uses' => 'ProjectCollaboratorsController@addPermission',
    'as'   => 'projects.collaborators.permission',
  //  'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

Data insert works properly, but update doesn't work.
When I click button to update it is inserts as new record to the database.

My table name is permission and have the following columns

- id (autoincrement)
- status
- project_id
- collaborator_id

What do I need to change to make the updating work?

Comment: When you update do you receive the updated success message or the added message, I mean on $msg

Comment: when I update I received added message

Comment: Ok, can you do a var_dump($permission) at the top of your function? before anything else, I just want to check what are you receiving as $permission on update.

Comment: can you put you mean code here little bit difficult understand your var_dump($permission)

Comment: Just before your if() add var_dump($permission);

Comment: And let us know what it shows

Comment: ok nothing special. same thing. only add new record not update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129341/discussion-between-phobia82-and-fernando).

Answer (score 1):

I see an error in this line, this should return the permission object not the id of permission.

$permission = Permission::findOrFail($permission,['id'])->id;
Change to,
$permission = Permission::findOrFail($permission['id']);

Comment: how can return id of the permission

Comment: did it but not sucess same problem

Comment: try to debug it using var_dump($permission->get()); what you see?

Comment: yes I can see all values of the table regarding current permission id like this **{"status":"1","project_id":"30","collaborator_id":"29","updated_at":"2016-11-29 09:59:48","created_at":"2016-11-29 09:59:48","id":126}**

Answer (score 0):

You should write this. Hopefully This will solve your problem

```
public function addPermission(Request $request, $id, $permission) 
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'status'   => 'required'
  ]);
  $per = Permission::where('id', $permission)->first();

  if(is_null($permission)) {
    $permission = new Permission;
    $msg = 'Permission has been added to your Collaborator successfully';
  } else {
    $permission = Permission::findOrFail($per)->id;
    $msg = 'Permission updated successfully';
  }

  $permission->status = $request->input('status');
  $permission->project_id       = $id;
  $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');
  $permission->save();
  return redirect()->back()->with('info', $msg);
}
```

Comment: Plz see this carefully  $permission = Permission::findOrFail($permission['id'])->id; @Fernando

Comment: did it same result

Comment: I did it but same thing. not update current values. only insert new record

Comment: @Fernando I have Updated my code. Please take a look. your problem is in that it the $permission variable did not get any value. Hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: same thing here

Comment: I updated my code right now. Please try this. @Fernando

Comment: alternatively, instead `->save()` use [`->updateOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to put an optional route parameter in for permission id.

```
Route::post('projects/{project_id}/permission/{permission_id?}', [
    'uses' => 'ProjectCollaboratorsController@addPermission',
    'as'   => 'projects.collaborators.permission',
  //  'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```